# Lists/Libraries: Why are not all existing fields exposed as site columns?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, site-column, internal-name

I was wondering what determines if an internal field of a list or library is made available as an actionable site column. More precisely, I was trying to add the published state  as a column in a site pages library. However, this field is not available to add as a site column but it exists as an internal field named **`_ModerationStatus`**. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could check if there is “published state” column in the site column. Go to site settings->Web Designer Galleries->site columns.

If there is no “published state” column in the site column, then the “published state” column is not the site column and cannot be added to the library or list.

It is by design.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, this column does not exist. What I wanted to achieve is if, for a Modern Communication Site, I wanted to show in a column if a site/article was published. As mentioned, there's the internal field _ModerationStatus. Is there any other way to show if a page is currently published?